# Automated testing tools available for odoo

Tags: testing, odoo, yaml

Is there any automated tool available for ODOO? Also, how does the YML File Structure work to use builtin add-ons in ODOO.

Answer (score 2):

Check runbot in https://github.com/odoo/odoo-extra repo.

This repository contains the source code of Odoo testing bot runbot.odoo.com. Please have a look in the runbot/ directory.

It may be help you.

Answer (score 1):

The Odoo Community Association uses TravisCI to perform tests on each build of their projects. The tooling that makes that possible is the [Maintainer Quality Tools](https://github.com/OCA/maintainer-quality-tools) project, and is suitable to be used in your own Odoo projects.